# SQL LIKE dosen't work from PHP but work in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I would like to use a LIKE form of query in SQL to auto-implement a text field with this php function :

```
function getNumOFAutoImplement($chaine){
   $o_CAD = new connect();

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_numero_affaire WHERE numero_OF LIKE \':numof%\'';

   $param = array(":numof"=>$chaine);
   $result = $o_CAD->read($sql, $param);
   return $result;
}
```

The function is working well went I use this request in my function :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_numero_affaire WHERE numero_OF LIKE :numof';
```

It's also working when I directly past the following line in the phpMyAdmin SQL box :

```
SELECT * FROM tb_numero_affaire WHERE numero_OF LIKE '%456%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sql ="SELECT * FROM tb_numero_affaire WHERE numero_OF LIKE '%".$chaine."%'";

Answer (score 2):

Bind it with the wildcards, like;

```
function getNumOFAutoImplement($chaine){
   $o_CAD = new connect();

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_numero_affaire WHERE numero_OF LIKE :numof';

   $param = array(":numof"=>$chaine.'%');
   $result = $o_CAD->read($sql, $param);
   return $result;
}
```

- Don't need to quote the placeholders as it will treat it as the literal string ':numof%'.

Comment: If you want the wildcard to check before and after not just after  `array(":numof"=>'%'.$chaine.'%')`